# Pick a random file from a directory in Java

Tags: java, file, random

I would like to pick a random file from any directory I want. such as
C:\Users\Josh\Pictures\[randomFile]

I have no code to show I just would like to know how I would come by doing that.

What I am fully doing is using a class to change the background of my desktop, and now I want to add a random file to it so when it refreshes the background will be different and I wont have to stop the running code to manually change the name of the file in the path. If you are wondering heres what it looks like

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class BackgroundTest {

    final static File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Pictures\\Pyimgur\\");
    static int size = 10;
    static String [] fileArray = new String[size];





public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(int i =0; i<size;i++){
        int idz = (int)(Math.random()*size);
        fileArray[i]=files[idz].getName();

    }

    for(String x: fileArray){
        System.out.print(x);
    }

    String path = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Pictures\\Pyimgur\\";
    String picture = "picture.jpg";
    //System.out.print(fileArray[0]);

    SPI.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(
            new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER),
            new UINT_PTR(0),
            path + picture,
            new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPI.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE));
}

public interface SPI extends StdCallLibrary {

    //from MSDN article
    long SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
    long SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    long SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

    SPI INSTANCE = (SPI) Native.loadLibrary("user32", SPI.class, new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
        {
            put(OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
            put(OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    });

    boolean SystemParametersInfo(
            UINT_PTR uiAction,
            UINT_PTR uiParam,
            String pvParam,
            UINT_PTR fWinIni
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always best to try to do something first before asking here, and showing your attempt with your question. In the very least, this will result in a much better and much more specific question. I'd also recommend that you remove any code not relevant to the problem at hand and any additional code needed to make your posted code runnable and compilable, and nothing more.

Comment: Basically, you want to get a list of the files in the directory, then use a random number generator to select one of them.  You sorta have that setup above (it's a little unclear why you construct `fileArray`), but you don't show how you use it, or explain what's wrong with what you have already.

Comment: Any issue you might be facing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create an `array` of the files within the given directory using `File.listFiles()`.
2. Select a file based on a random index from this array.
   That can be done with an instance of the `Random` class, using `Random.nextInt(int bound)`, where `bound`, in this case, is the amount of files in the `array`, thus the array's length.

---

Example:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

Random rand = new Random();

File file = files[rand.nextInt(files.length)];
```

Comment: Yes this works, however it prints out the full path name I just want the name of the file how would i do that?

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox That has nothing to do with the code passion provided here; that's the way you're printing. But as for the answer, that would be done with `file.getName()`

Comment: @Passion No problem! Everyone starts somewhere and I'm happy to nudge you in the right direction and help you grow! =)

Answer (score 1):

Scan the directory to make a list of the files in it, and then pick a random index from that list.

Then build upon that principle by filtering for valid files only (image files, in this case); avoiding the picking of the same image as the current one; and other such improvements...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks Hovercraft. =) I feel like my answer is a bit too short and basic tho... I'll expand on it in an edit later, if the OP provides what he has attempted.