# How to get a random file from a random folder

Tags: java, random, directory

**This is not a duplicate of "Counting the number of files in a directory using Java", since the main question here is "How to get a random file from a random folder". Counting the number of files was just an optional question for improvement.**

I have a folder "testfiles" in my project directory, which contains a lot of others folders. Those folders all have names like "alice-g" (firstname and then first letter from lastname). Each of those folders contains some other folders, not always the same number. And in each of those last folders, i got a bunch of files, all named with number ("1.", "2.", "3." and so on).

What i want to do is going into this "testfiles" directory, randomly select a folder, get his name, then randomly select another folder in it and finally select a random file in this folder (and get his name).

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629645/pick-a-random-file-from-a-directory-in-java) which say we can pick a random file from a folder this way:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
Random rand = new Random();
File file = files[rand.nextInt(files.length)];
```

This sound clear and easy to me. However, since all my files have "easy numbered names", i wonder if there is a way to do this without making a list of all files. Getting the total number of files in the directory should be enough to me, since their names are just number with a "."

Second, this solve the problem of selecting a random file, but not of selecting a random directory (and get his name).

**EDIT:** 
I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715607/by-java-how-to-count-file-numbers-in-a-directory-without-list) which says that a "good solution" (fast) to count the number of files OR directories in a directory is:

```
File hugeDir = new File("/tmp/huge-dir");
int numberFiles = hugeDir.list().length;
```

I totally didn't know that we could create a File object with a directory. Seems weird to me. However, i guess it can solve both of my question: to select a random directory and get his name, i do:

```
//Get a random client name according to directories names:
private static String getRandomClient() {
    File testFiles = new File("testfiles");  //directory where all my testfiles are (in other directories)
    Random rand = new Random();
    String[] dirNames = testFiles.list();   //making a list() seems to be faster than making a listFiles().
    File randomNamedDirectory = new File(dirNames[rand.nextInt(dirNames.length)]);
    String randomDirName = randomNamedDirectory.getName();
    return randomDirName;
}
```

Then i want to get a random file from a random directory from this client Directory:

```
//Get a random File Path from the client Directory:
private static String getRandomFilePath(String clientDirectory) {
    File clientDir = new File("testfiles\\"+clientDirectory);   //client Directory.
    System.out.println(clientDir);
    Random rand = new Random();
    String[] dirNames = clientDir.list();  //This return null!?
    System.out.println(dirNames);
    File randomDirectory = new File(dirNames[rand.nextInt(dirNames.length)]);
    int numberFiles = randomDirectory.list().length;
    String randomFile = rand.nextInt(numberFiles) + ".";  //All files are named with their number and a .
    String filePath = clientDir + "\\" + randomDirectory +"\\" + randomFile;
    return filePath;
}
```

The first function works well; however, in the second one, the list of Directories Names is null. Since it's just the same code as before, i don't understand why.

Comment: You say that files have "easy numbered names". Can you show a sample directory structure with some folders and files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the number of files in a directory using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687444/counting-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-java)

Comment: Is this question about "get the number of files in a directory (without making this list of all files)?" or "selecting a random directory (and get his name)."?

Comment: @M.Taylor yeah that basically mirrors what I would say about this subject. If performance is an issue (and there is absolutely no proof here that it is an issue as no testing has been performed), then let the OS do the work for you.

Comment: The example you found is very good. What is the reason why you want to do it differently? If it is optimization, what kind of performance figures are you getting now?

Comment: Well, the main question is still "getting a random directory". It's just, while writting it i thought maybe with my structure i can have a better way to select a random file. but since i have no idea how to select a random directory, i didn't test it yet. Maybe it'll be fast enough....but i'll have to do this a lot of time. So making a lot of file list just to get their length seems a bit...overwork?

Comment: @MasterChief: Sample directory structure: 
In directory "alice-g", i have 3 directories "document", "deleted", "to_do". Each of those directories contains files, whose names are just numbers. "to_do" contains 4 files: "1.", "2.", "3.", "4.", "document" contains 184 files, so the last file is named "184.". "deleted" contains 255 files so the last file name is "255."

Answer (score 0):

So, after some research, i found out that: 
1. It seems that there is not really a better solution than making a list of the files. However, using list() instead of listFiles() seems to be a bit faster (see the post cited in the EDIT part of the question)

2. The "partial solution" i give in my question have some stupid mistakes in it (like, using \ instead of / ). Here is a "minimal and complete" solution:

.

```
import java.io.File;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String client = getRandomClient(); 
        String filePath = getRandomFilePath(client);
        File file = new File(filePath);        
    }

    //Get a random client name according to directories names:
    private static String getRandomClient() {
        File testFiles = new File("maildir");  //directory where all my testfiles are (in other directories)
        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] dirNames = testFiles.list();
        File randomNamedDirectory = new File(dirNames[rand.nextInt(dirNames.length)]);
        String randomDirName = randomNamedDirectory.getName();
        return randomDirName;
    }

    //Get a random File Path from the client Directory:
    private static String getRandomFilePath(String clientDirectory) {
        File clientDir = new File("maildir/"+clientDirectory);      //client Directory.
        System.out.println(clientDir);
        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] dirNames = clientDir.list();
        File randomDirectory = new File(clientDir +"/" + dirNames[rand.nextInt(dirNames.length)]);
        int numberFiles = randomDirectory.list().length;
        String randomFile = rand.nextInt(numberFiles) + ".";  //All files are named with their number and a .
        String filePath = randomDirectory + "/" + randomFile;
        return filePath;
    }
```